# Factors included in the average density of planets

Tags: planet, density

When the average density for a planet is stated does it incorporate the mass of the atmosphere, when a planet has an atmosphere, or is the mass of the atmosphere ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether of not you include the *mass* of the atmosphere doesn't matter much. For instance, the mass of Earth's atmosphere is roughly $10^{-6}$ of Earth's mass, corresponding to the uncertainty in the gravitational constant $G$ used to calculate the mass in the first place.

But the *volume* that you use for calculating the average density could potentially matter, depending on your definition of the height of the atmosphere. For Earth, the lowest-orbiting satellites are at a height of $\sim100\,\mathrm{km}$, so if you include that, your volume will be 5% larger. This number can be much lower if you define the height of the atmosphere to be the scale height (0.3%), or much higher if you include the thermosphere (1600%).

Because the height of the atmosphere is quite arbitrary, this is rarely if ever included in the average density of a (rocky) planet.

Comment: For gas giants the gaseous component obviously has to be included both for the mass and the volume. So I believe that for reasons of consistency, this will be done too, for the rocky planets. A common convention is to take as radius the radius of the 1 bar level of atmospheric pressure, which will yield comparative radii for most planets and moons with atmospheres, and those without.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape You're probably right. I know about the "1 bar" rule, but I don't know whether or not the part above this arbitrary height is included in the mass. But it would make sense if it were.